# Inter-ViewController parameters passing in iPhone programming... how to?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, viewcontroller

I read: [iPhone: How to Pass Data Between Several Viewcontrollers in a Tabbar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363777/iphone-how-to-pass-data-between-several-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbar-app) and was wondering what is the difference between

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate]
```

and

```
extern struct* global
```

?

Conceptually, I don't see how [[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate] not being a global thing. In fact, that lessen the sense of guilty when using the dirty global struct * now.

I am starting a new project very soon. So, I use this break to ask the question: is there any **best-practice code example** to illustrate how to share data between two ViewControllers (but not globally)?

Let me put it in an example:

- this is a game
- there is a NSString *name to store the player's name
- there is a NSInteger score to store the player's current score
- the GameMainViewController will update and display the score
- in the GameSettingViewController, there is a text field to edit name and a button to reset score
- the GameMainViewController is responsible for set a default name (if nil), save both name and score when exit, load both (if exists) when start

so

- where should I put "name" and "score"?
- how can both ViewControllers access and change the values

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store name and score in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Retrieve an item:

```
NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Setting an item:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"Horace" forKey:@"name"];
```

Also, if this is data that you want to preserve across launches of the app, you may want to archive it into a plist.