# what is the best way to share an object between different views in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I developing an app, and I have an object with data from the user but this object has to be used in different views.
I would like to know the best and more light way to share the object between differents views.

Actually I have the object in the appDelegate and I'm trying to access by the following method

```
yourObject* obj = [(YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] yourObject];
```

Comment: Doesn't the code you show work?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714309/inter-viewcontroller-parameters-passing-in-iphone-programming-how-to) before. I think you can choose among `app delegate`, `global extern` and `NSUserDefaults`.