# How to pass data between different UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

**What is the best way to pass data from one view controller to another?**

Suppose I push another view controller onto the present view controller. If I have to give some data to the view being pushed from the present view controller how do I do it?

Also how do I pass data from the pushed view to the earlier view?

So far I have done this by declaring functions in each controller and calling them. I find it dirty and want a cleaner way to do this. I don't want to use plists or sqlite as the data isn't that significant.

Comment: Yeah. Facing this situation in iphone sdk

Comment: Did you try [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=view+controller+pass+data)? This is quite an often asked question.

Comment: I did but I still couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can,t you try making the variable in `AppDelegate`.Give that data to the variable of the AppDelegate and fetch it wherever you want in your application or `UIViewControllers` you will get that data.That value will be assigned to the the variable of the app delegate upto the `termination` of the `application`.

Try taking help from already asked several times **[Pass Data Between Several Viewcontrollers in a App.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363777/iphone-how-to-pass-data-between-several-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbar-app)**

Hope you get my point .....Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the data in AppDelegate is not a good idea if the amount of data is quite large since the data will live throughout the application lifecycle.

Why not call the setter(s) of the newly created `UIViewController` object to pass the data so that you can release it if the view goes offscreen or gets deallocated.

Comment: I'm confused as to why calling a property setter was not an immediately given answer.

Comment: I have already used the property setter. But it gives errors sometimes and is not a good way to set variables.

Comment: What errors? And why do you say it is not a good way? Setters are specifically created in the framework to set variables.

Comment: Because for passing the variables, I need to declare them as a property for the respective classes. This leads to a lot of variables being declared. Also, as I said, the data required is temporary and shouldn't be actually declared as properties. The code gets really dirty. On top of that, I have to do memory management for each declared variable.

Comment: Why not create a "Model" object that contains all the variables. If done correctly, simply releasing this object will result in releasing the variables it contains.